# How Do I rotate without bound exceed composition size in after Effects CC

Tags: adobe-after-effects, rotate

Hello I want rotate this
[image]

But... I have problem rotating this
[image]

I want rotate without exceed bound.
How can I fix this problem? 
sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

A few options...

1. Scale the layer so that it doesn't exceed the composition's bounds. Just find the point where it exceeds the bounds the most and scale so that it no longer does. Obviously this means your layer is now smaller, which may not be what you want. Alternatively just increase the size of your composition...
2. Don't use a 3D rotation at all. Unlinking the "scale" properties and animating only the horizontal scale from "100%" to "-100%" and back again will give you a completely flat faux horizontal rotation.

   [image]
3. Use a camera to affect the perspective. This may be more complicated depending on your project setup but will probably give you the best result if you can make it work.

   All you need to do is create a new camera, set its position further away and increase the zoom to compensate. The further away the camera, the less perspective you will have.

   [image]